# Do I need a Primary Key in a simple table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, primary-key

Imagine I have a table with only 2 columns (`FK`s to other tables). I want to define "the primary key of this table is the combination of the 2 values".

What happens if I don't have a `PK` in this kind of table?

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? Nothing special happens.

Comment: If your table lacks a key then it is not a true representation of the external reality it is supposed to represent. It will be difficult for users to make use of the data or to verify or update it accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a `UNIQUE` constraint or unique index defined on the two columns, the table could have duplicate rows.

Also, a primary key is a clustered index by default: you would need to separately index the table for expected query performance.

Refer to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3820213/1810429) and [yet another SO question declared as a duplicate of it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19020934/1810429) regarding the differences between primary key & unique constraints and unique indexes.